# Oracle Query: How do I get only records that have a date after a value type is found?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called `item_log` with this sample data

```
LOG_ID   | LOG_TYPE  | LOG_DATE
401      | R1        | 1-1-2018
401      | R2        | 1-2-2018
401      | R3        | 2-2-2018
401      | R1        | 2-3-2018
401      | R2        | 3-1-2018
402      | R1        | 1-1-2018
402      | R2        | 1-2-2018
402      | R3        | 2-2-2018
403      | R1        | 1-1-2018
403      | R2        | 1-2-2018
403      | R3        | 2-2-2018
404      | R1        | 1-1-2018
404      | R2        | 1-2-2018
404      | R3        | 2-2-2018
404      | R4        | 2-4-2018
404      | R5        | 5-2-2018
```

I need to show only the `LOG_ID` records that have a date occurring after the TYPE `R3`.

I am guessing it would be a subquery but I am a novice at doing them and new to oracle so any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance for the knowledge.

the results would show something like this:

```
LOG_ID   | TYPE  | LOG_DATE
401      | R3    | 2-2-2018
404      | R3    | 2-2-2018
```

Comment: What will happen with your expected result if `log_id = 401` have one more row `R3` with date `4-4-2018`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lead()`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=848da8ee1006e7a8078d85d05d68ce1d)**

```
select * from
(
select *,lead(log_type) over(partition by log_id order by log_date) as nextlog
from t 
)A where log_type='R3' and nextlog is not null
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
log_id  log_type    log_date
401      R3         02/02/2018 00:00:00
404      R3         02/02/2018 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the values whose type is R3
in that case simply add that in the where clause
like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Log_id, Type, Log_Date 
FROM item_log
WHERE log_type = 'R3';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query:

```
SELECT log_id, log_type, 
    MAX(log_date)
FROM item_log l
WHERE log_type = 'R3'
GROUP BY log_id, log_type
HAVING MAX(log_date) < (
        SELECT MAX(log_date)
        FROM item_log
        WHERE log_id = l.log_id
    );
```